# dnsmasq less verbose?

Tags: dnsmasq

Is it possible to make dnsmasq less verbose?

I couldn't find any hints in the manual page / the internet.

The only options I have found are already uncommented:

```
# For debugging purposes, log each DNS query as it passes through
# dnsmasq.
#log-queries

# Log lots of extra information about DHCP transactions.
#log-dhcp
```

Answer (score 2):

dnsmasq's long manpage lists some options to quieten some routine operations:

```
   --quiet-dhcp, --quiet-dhcp6, --quiet-ra
          Suppress  logging  of  the  routine operation of these protocols.
          Errors and problems will still be logged. --quiet-dhcp and quiet-
          dhcp6 are over-ridden by --log-dhcp.
```